# What is the travelled distance of the red mark on the upper surface of the rotating cube?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, pi

> Each side of a cube is **2 unit** in length. This cube is kept on a
>   table such a way that **one surface** (i.e., **4** vertices) of it
>   completely touches the table. At this position, a **red point** is
>   drawn on the center of the **upper surface**. Now the cube is being
>   rotated along a straight line towards a certain direction. At the time
>   of rotation, at least **two vertices** of the cube are in touch with
>   the table. Rotation is stopped when the red mark reached its initial
>   position. Total distance traveled by the red mark is
>   $$(\sqrt{{b}}+1)\pi$$
>
> **What is the value of b?**

Source: [Bangladesh Math Olympiad 2017](https://www.matholympiad.org.bd/)

I am facing trouble to find the distance travelled by the red mark. Is it a straight line from start to end or a curved line (almost a circle) which is travelled by the red mark at every rotation of the cube?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, the answer should be b=5 as seen from the following picture:

[image: path]

Answer (score 1):

The cube is rolled keeping one edge on the table at each time.  As it is rolled around each edge the red point traces a quarter circle with radius the distance to the edge of rotation.  For the first edge the point is $\sqrt 5$ away from the edge because we have a $1-2-\sqrt 5$ triangle from the center of the edge to the point, so the point moves $\frac \pi 2 \sqrt 5$.  Then the point is $1$ from the edge of rotation for the next one, so it traces $\frac \pi 2$.  The third edge has the point starting from the center bottom, again $1$ from the center, and we get another $\frac \pi 2$.  The final one has the point $\sqrt 5$ away again, so we get a total of 
$$\frac \pi 2(2+2\sqrt 5)=\pi(1+\sqrt 5)\\b=5$$